# Section of website to be protected by a login

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I have a section of my website where I will have forms. I only want people who have registered with the site to be able to use these forms so that I only have serious customers using them. 
So what i want to have is a way that people can register on the site and once registered the area with the forms will be available to them and I will know who has sent me a form etc.

Comment: Yes, that's a very common scenario. And your question is...?

Answer (score 3):

use session
for example after he login use **session_register("myusername");**

and in your website, put this

session_start();
if(session_is_registered(myusername))
{
// your forms
};

Answer (score 2):

after he login use $_SESSION['login']=1;

if your site :

if(isset($_SESSION['login']))

{

// your forms
};

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-login-system-for-a-simple-website/) is what you need?